# How to python regex match the following?

Tags: python, regex

```
1<assume tab here>Algebra I<assume tab here>START
1.1 What are the Basic Numbers? 1-1
```

For each of the two lines above, how do I regex match only the number up to and including the "?". In essence, I want the following groups:

```
["1", "Algebra I"]
["1.1", "What are the Basic Numbers?"]
```

Matching everything up to and including a question mark, or up to a "tab character". 
How can I do this with a single regex?

Comment: Perhaps regex are overkill - for the first line you can use `line.split('\t')[:2]` and the second `" ".join(line.split()[:-1]).split(' ', 1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an easy regex:

```
^([\d.]+)\s*([^\t?]+\??)
```

Group 1 is the numbers, Group 2 contains the text.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

To retrieve one single match:

```
match = re.search(r"^([\d.]+)\s*([^\t?]+\??)", s)
if match:
    mynumbers = match.group(1)
    myline = match.group(2)
```

To iterate over the matches, get groups 1 and 2 from:

```
reobj = re.compile(r"^([\d.]+)\s*([^\t?]+\??)", re.MULTILINE)
for match in reobj.finditer(s):
    # matched text: match.group()
```

Comment: This regex is missing the question mark at the end of the OP's second example line.

Comment: @rolando added Python code, not that you need it. :)

Comment: Ah, there you go. Now you've got it.

Comment: @JustinBarber I had made the edit in the Python code and forgotten about the regex at the top. :) Cheers

Comment: @hwnd My test input has the two lines, and I'm anchoring at the head. :)

Comment: @hwnd but you're right that the code doesn't iterate, it just gets the first match.

Comment: @hwnd Yes, sure. I use that a lot. Don't ask me why I sometimes set the flag, sometimes the mode. You have a preference. ?

Comment: It's basically user preference =)

Comment: @hwnd split the code into single-match (no multiline) and multi-match.

Comment: @hwnd Yeah I too tend to go with `(?m)` because it's in your face, but in this case didn't for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
(\d(?:\.\d)*)\s+(?:(.*?\?|.*?)\t)
```

For explanation: `(\d(?:\.\d)*)` matches a number followed by zero or more `.\d`'s. this is followed by one or more whitespace characters followed by anything (that is lazy and not greedy) with `(.*?)` which is followed by either ? or \t in a non-capturing group.

Output:

```
 string1 = "1.1 What are the Basic Numbers? 1-1"
 string2 = '1\tAlgebra I\tSTART'
 m = re.match(pattern, string2)
 m.group(1)
#'1'
 m.group(2)
#'Algebra I'
 m = re.match(pattern, string1)
 m.group(1)
#'1.1'
 m.group(2)
#'What are the Basic Numbers?'
```

EDIT: added non-capturing groups.

EDIT#2: fixed it to include question mark

EDIT#3 fixed no of groups.

Comment: Is there a way to accomodate for space or tab? I know the \s+ is for space only.

Comment: @Rolando what do you mean?

Comment: \s matches: `[ \t\n\r\f\v]` [see docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: I see that your answer appears to return ["1.1", ".1",  "What are the Basic Numbers?"] for the second line.

Comment: for some odd reason, the first line captures as ["", "Algebra I"]

Comment: @Rolando do you have the updated regex there? I could show you my repl, works fine for me.

Comment: I think you are missing the question mark. The question mark should not appear in the non-capturing group per the OP's example of line 2.

Comment: @zx81 nice and concise. +1

Comment: Close. But now you have three groups, so that your python code doesn't quite work how you show it.